# Static IP for Azure Mobile Service?

Tags: azure-mobile-services, static-ip-address

Does Microsoft Azure offer static IP for Mobile Service, or static IP can only be allocated for Azure Cloud Services and VMs?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think so at first, but apparently you can.

See: [Set Azure VM Static IP Address](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-azure/set-azure-vm-static-ip-address)

Comment: Thanks for the info! However, the link shows how to set static IP for Azure VM, but what I want is for Azure Mobile Service. Any idea?

Comment: Are you able to share the need for a static IP address?  Is not a CNAME sufficient?

Comment: @BrendanGreen One need for a static IP on a Mobile Service is if our mobile service needs to connect to some third party API/service that needs to allow our IPs through their firewalls..